# Listing arrays in handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have an array in my Node js file. I want it to render a hbs file where I also send the array as a JSON object. How can I list the array or loop through thee array individually in the hbs file?

My Node js snippet

```
app.get('/RC_main',(req,res) =>{
 con.query("USE HOSTEL;",function(err,value){
   //  if(err)// throw err
     console.log("Done-use")
 })
 var name = ['Aa','ase','aqwe']
 var names = []
 for(var i=0;i<name.length;i++){
 names.push({
   name : name[i]
 })
}
console.log(name)
 const studNames = JSON.stringify(name)
 res.render('RC_main.hbs',{
   studNames
 })

})
```

Comment: Where is your Handlebars template?

Comment: @76484 I just want to know how to list them. I don't have a handlebars template right now.